# Apache License 2.0 - Beginner

Tags: apache-license

I'm building close-source application with some libraries that's using Apache License 2.0.

Number 4 point a) of the license stated that:

```
(a) You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a copy of this License;
```

Does this mean that my application is now under Apache License 2.0 because I included that license to my app?
Where should I include this license? In my source code or on the GUI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the Apache license isn't a "copyleft" license.  You must include the license in your stuff so that the end user knows that they are using something Apache licensed.  In your read me or wherever you plan on putting your license I would include a section that says uses Apache (whatever you are using here) Licensed under Apache 2.0 (license text here). If you have a click through agreement during the install then it is just another click through there. Basically put it as an addendum to wherever you were planning on putting your license.

The apache site has an [FAQ](https://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#WhatDoesItMEAN) about their license:

> It requires you to:
>
> include a copy of the license in any redistribution you may make that includes Apache software;
>
> provide clear attribution to The Apache Software Foundation for any distributions that include Apache software.